# WPF WrapPanel, GroupBox height

Tags: wpf, dynamic, wrappanel

I've got a few GroupBoxes containing different number of controls, mostly TextBlocks and TextBoxes, and thereby of different heights. 
I generate these GroupBoxes dynamically.

When the WrapPanel is quite narrow you could easily see that the GroupBoxes is of different heights but when the WrapPanel is resized, wider, the layout is rearranged (as it should) but at the same time the GroupBox rearranged gets the same height as the one to its left.

Is there a way to prevent this?

What i want to achieve.

```
------------  ------------ 
| BLOCK #1 |  | BLOCK #1 |
------------  |          |
------------  |          |
| BLOCK #2 |  |          |
|          |  |          |
------------  ------------
```

Thanks! 
//Robert

Comment: `WrapPanel` allocates either fixed height(Vertical orientation) or fixed width(Horizontal orientation) for its child elements based on its orientation. This may be the reason for that behavior.

Comment: Perhaps `DockPanel` may be better suited for this layout

Comment: Thanks @Mathew, Orientation="Vertical" did the trick!